Decomposing Returns into Systematic and Idiosyncratic Components Using Eigenvectors of a Known Covariance Matrix
I am working with a factor model where stock returns are given by the equation:
$r=\beta^Tf+\epsilon$
where

$r$ is an n-dimensional vector of returns
$f$ is a k-dimensional vector of factor returns
$\beta$ is n x k matrix of factor loadings
$\epsilon$ is n-dimensional vector of idiosyncratic returns

I have a known covariance matrix $\Omega$ of the returns, which is created from known beta and factor covariance and diagonal specific risk.
$\Omega = \beta \Omega_f \beta^T + \Omega_\epsilon$
I also have some random data X generated from the beta and factor covariance (forming the known systematic component) and from the stock specific risk (forming the known idiosyncratic component).
My goal is to decompose the returns into systematic and idiosyncratic components, but I only know $\Omega$. I do not know $\beta$ or $\Omega_f$ and I cannot see $f$.
To achieve this, I am using the first few eigenvectors Q of the covariance matrix $\Omega$. Experiments using this random data show that X.Q.Q’ are a good approximation for the systematic component of returns.
However, X.Q.Q’ does not perfectly result in the known systematic returns. I understand that this is because $Q$ and $\beta$ are not the same thing. Yet they are clearly related since the decomposition is a good approximation.
My question is, is there any way to calculate an expectation of the goodness of the approximation (something like $R^2$) for a given $\Omega$?
Sample code demonstrating the decomposition
set.seed(123)
n_secs <- 50
n_factor <- 7

beta <- runif(n = n_secs * n_factor) |> matrix(ncol = n_factor)

factor_var <- runif(n = n_factor, min = 0.5) |> diag()

common_risk <- beta %*% factor_var %*% t(beta)

specific_vars <- runif(n = n_secs, min = 0.2, max = 0.4) * 10

covar <- common_risk + diag(specific_vars)

n_days <- 1000

factor_returns <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = n_days, Sigma = factor_var, mu = rep(0, n_factor))
systematic_returns <- factor_returns %*% t(beta)
idio_returns <- sapply(1:n_secs, \(i_sec)rnorm(n = n_days, sd = sqrt(specific_vars[i_sec])))
returns = systematic_returns + idio_returns

evv <- eigen(covar)
zv <- evv$vectors[,1:n_factor, drop = FALSE]

est_syst_returns_v <- returns %*% zv %*% t(zv)

plot(systematic_returns[,1], est_syst_returns_v[,1], asp = 1)
abline(a = 0, b = 1, col = "blue")

The estimated systematic returns are a good approximation to the known systematic returns, but not perfect. Can I estimate how good an approximation for a given $\Omega$? Even I cannot perform this estimate, can I at least justify this transformation using some analytical argument? All I have now is the above empirical/numerical experiment.

